# Problems with textboxes and page load in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay here I have some code from my project at the moment.

Basically the user goes onto the page and their current password is in the password textbox, and their avatar is selected in the droplist.

They can change their password by editing the text in the textbox and change their avatar by selecting a new one from the list. This is then written to the file where this information is kept. It writes to the file okay, but it writes what was initially in the textbox and droplist.

If i comment out these lines in the page load:

```
avatarDropList.SelectedValue = Session["avatar"].ToString();

newPasswordTextbox.Text = Session["password"].ToString();
```

It updates the file properly, but this is not what I want as I want the old password displayed there initially as well as the avatar to be selected in the dropbox.

Code below:

```
public partial class TuitterProfile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        avatarImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/avatars/" + Session["avatar"] + ".gif";
        avatarDropList.SelectedValue = Session["avatar"].ToString();
        userNameTextbox.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
        newPasswordTextbox.Text = Session["password"].ToString();
    }

    protected void okButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Session["user"].ToString();
        string password = Session["password"].ToString();
        string newPassword = newPasswordTextbox.Text;
        string newAvatar = avatarDropList.SelectedValue;
        int allDataReference = -1;

        //Each element in the array is a string(Username Password Avatar)
        string[] allData = File.ReadAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < allData.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] user = allData[i].Split(' ');
            if (user[0] == username && user[1] == password)
            {
                allDataReference = i;
            }
        }

        if (allDataReference > -1)
        {
            Session["avatar"] = newAvatar;
            Session["password"] = newPassword;
            allData[allDataReference] = username + " " + newPassword + " " + newAvatar; 
            File.WriteAllLines(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/tuitterUsers3.txt", allData);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please rename the question to make it more descriptive

Comment: Thanks to whoever fixed it I didn't have much idea what I was doing :)

Comment: @Sachin Sorry I don't come here often I'll change it. Why negative votes? :(

Comment: @user2256772 indeed, I don't know why the downvotes; people: if something is missing from the question: *ask about it*

Comment: Or just read the code, in this case it was immediately obvious what the problem is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the ASP.Net page event lifecycle, Page_Load is called on every request. What you are doing here is resetting the value of the TextBox every time the page loads, which will include the time that you press the button to save the profile.

All you need to do is check for the current request being a postback when you set your initial values:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        avatarImage.ImageUrl = "~/images/avatars/" + Session["avatar"] + ".gif";
        avatarDropList.SelectedValue = Session["avatar"].ToString();
        userNameTextbox.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
        newPasswordTextbox.Text = Session["password"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks. Funny how one of the only other questions I've asked on here before was for the same reason. Thanks man.

Comment: It can take a while to sink in, maybe this will help for the future: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx =]

Comment: Thank you. I shall educate myself on that immediately!